# Adding numbers to array elements

Tags: javascript

I want to add some number to elements of any array but I get NaN. I know why we have all NaN. Just want to know a way to do something similar.

```js
var a = [];

for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<2;j++){
    var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    a[i] += random_number
  } 
}

console.log(a) //[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

Answer (score 1):

`+= ...` is appending `...` to whatever was previously in your variable. Here, it's appending a number to an unset value, giving `NaN`.

Just get rid of your `+=` when setting your array values :

```js
var a = [];

for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<2;j++){
        var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        a[i] = random_number;
    }   
}

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a default value of zero instead of `undefined` for addition.

```js
var a = [],
    i, j, random_number;

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        a[i] = (a[i] || 0) + random_number;
    }
}

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Thank, I missed parentheses . I tried a[i] || 0 + random_number and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **'+='** , instead just use **'='**

You are assigning a number to an unassigned variable. That's why you are getting NaN error.